# What is the general feeling of Esperanto speakers toward Esperantidos?

Tags: culture

Some people in history weren't happy with Esperanto, and created offshoots of it, called Esperantidos (like Ido).

Since current Esperanto speakers are *de facto* more or less happy with it, what do they generally think of this "offspring"?
Do they see it rather positively, or with despise, because of how it's a threat to the cohesion of Esperantujo, or maybe they just don't care?

Comment: Even though I'm also interested in this question, wouldn't any possible answer be opinion-based? I doubt there is any research or something to use as a reference for a concrete answer. But I might be wrong.

Comment: Maybe some people will have gotten a general idea out of talking about it with other Esperanto speakers?

Comment: In the main Telegram group for Esperanto there are frequently jokes about Ido speakers who are portrayed as the enemy of Esperanto. However I'm sure this is only intended as a light-hearted joke, even if it is arguably somewhat in bad taste, and there is no real animosity towards Ido speakers.

Answer (score 6):

Short answer: There is no "general feeling of Esperanto speakers" about anything. Any question starting with "What do Esperanto speakers think of ..." can't be answered in a general way.

Comment: Ironically, you did answer all those questions in a general way... ;-)

Comment: If you feel that some question doesn't really fit the site, vote to close it and (probably) down-vote.

Answer (score 5):

It's going to be incredibly hard for anyone to come with a decent answer to this that is not opinion-based, but below is my general impression from attending a few international meetups with other Esperantists.

While [finvenkismo](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fina_Venko) is still very prevalent in the Esperanto community it is my impression, especially among the younger generations, that it is slowly fading away. That is to say, it is not unsupported but the desire to fight for Esperanto as an international auxilliary language is not as such.

And that's one of the main reasons people would not support an Esperantido; to protect Esperanto, and the position as the international language, from potential competitors.

At the latest IJK in Wrocław, Poland, which I attended I heard Ido spoken on multiple occasions and I believe even Popido once.

**In summary** it is my impression that Esperantidoj are generally not appreciated but increasingly tolerated.

Comment: And I sung a few songs in Toki Pona at IJK with some friends there. Albeit, Toki Pona is not an Esperantido, but yeah... I'd say Esperanto speakers are much less hostile to conlangs than conlangers are to Esperanto. :-/

Comment: @ChuckSmith I think there is a significant difference of feeling toward other languages designed to be an international auxiliary language (esperantido or otherwise), than toward languages that never had that goal, such as toki pona.